# Moment.js событие изменения || Moment.js || JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Как подвеситься на событие изменение данных в moment.js? Как понять, что данные изменились? Может есть такая встроенная функция?

Comment: Откуда у вас данные а моментс?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не понял вопроса. Moment.js создается с помощью moment().